# Set Date range from a specific date instead of month in CalendarView

Tags: android, kotlin, calendarview

https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView

I have been using this library for setting up an horizontal calendar view. In this library they set Date range like this:-

```
  val currentMonth = YearMonth.now()
      
  binding.mainSingleRowCalendar.setup(
      currentMonth,
      currentMonth.plusMonths(2),
      DayOfWeek.values().random()
  )
```

Here the month is used to set the date range. i need it to be a specific date. Is there any work around?
My actual requirement is to show past 30 days from current date.

Answer (score 0):

**of(int year, int month) method**

Obtains an instance of YearMonth from a year and month.

```
YearMonth.of(2021,9) // Sample
```

Comment: i need to specify the day